# Jest Error Unexpected token on react component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

[image]

I am getting Unexpected token on the `React Component Name` while running `npm test`. Tried reading several other similar questions but none seems to be working for me. I have added content of babelrc , package.json and my test file content below

```html
<!-- content of .babelrc file -->
{ "presets": ["env"] }

<!-- content of package.son file -->
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.0.0-alpha.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.3",
    "jest": "^22.4.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "notify": true,
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./src/setupTests.js",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }

<!-- Content of Test file App.test.js -->
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import App from '../../src/components/App';

// describe what we are testing
describe('Render App Component', () => {
 
 // make our assertion and what we expect to happen 
 it('should render without throwing an error', () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    expect(wrapper.find('.app__wrapper').length).toEqual(1);
 })
})
```

Comment: is `.babelrc` in your root directory?

Comment: Yes I confirm .babelrc is in root right next to package.json :)

Comment: Hmm, ok.. I vaguely recall having this same problem, I'm trying hard to remember what I did to solve it

Comment: If its of some help if I change content of .babelrc file to `{ "presets": ["env","react"] }` error changes to https://i.imgur.com/y0qKrN6.png so tests start reading my css file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I resolved the issue.

  • Add the following content to your .babelrc file and make sure .babelrc is in the root folder

```
{ "presets": ["env","react"] }
```

  • Make sure you exclude static assets like CSS, images, SCSS, PDF, fonts, etc. Add the following to package.json as highlighted in the screenshot

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
    "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
  "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
}
```

---

Screenshot:

[image: exclude-static-assets]

Answer (score 0):

If anybody comes here to figure out what is happening, I think the accepted answer is not related to the issue here.

When the file extension is `.js` and if you try to write JSX in that file, linter will complain if you have a correct ESlint configuration.

Instead, try to change the file extension to `.jsx` **or** `.tsx` (if Typescript involved).